# In curl, how do I force header content-type to application/json?

Tags: curl

Hello I am trying to follow the tutorial on this page:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_index_and_query_a_document.html

In this part we are adding a customer. However, when I follow the instructions (copy as curl and paste in cmd), I get an error 406.

The curl instruction copied pastes into cmd exactly as follows:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
'
```

Which results in each line being individually processed (not sure of the correct terminology):
[screen-cap of cmd showing each line being processed. ugh.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDZFN.png)

Which uncorks a fountain of errors.

If I copy it all into one line, it looks like this:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H'Content-Type:json' -d '{  "name": "John Doe"}'
```

Which isn't quite so redic but still gives me an error:

```
{
  "error" : "Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported",
  "status" : 406
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9
```

Which is strange because I **didn't plinkin set the content type to that, it's pretty clear I set it to json.** (sorry I've wasted half my weekend on this and I'm tired of it.)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or some good places to start looking? I know there's a lot of config that could be wrong, but everything has worked up till now; the PUT and GET requests on the previous page worked, so I don't know why this all of a sudden doesn't work.

Comment: do you have an elasctisearch up and running locally? seems you are in windows and probably don't have it (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html)

Answer (score 3):

there are several problems here,

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' 
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
'
```

this scheme with `'` for multiline is not supported in Microsoft's terminal emulator, cmd, which you are apparently using. The equivalent cmd command would be:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' ^
{ ^
  "name": "John Doe" ^
} ^
'
```

but instead of using cmd for this, I highly recommend you install a better terminal instead, like the [Cygwin Terminal](https://www.cygwin.com/), which supports the linux terminal newline scheme of `'` (and `\`, by the way.) - it's apparent that the api documentation you are reading already assumes you are using a linux-style terminal, so instead of converting linux-formatted commands to windows cmd format (which you are evidently not qualified for), you should instead install a linux-style terminal (like Cygwin.)

another problem: when the API is hit with the header `Content-Type:json`, it will respond with `Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported`

- this is a bug in the target API, you should send a bugreport to the API devs, it should have responded: `Content-Type header [Content-Type:json] is not supported`

another problem: `If I copy it all into one line, it looks like this:`

- you copied it wrong, you ended up with `-H'Content-Type:json'` , it should have been `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`